# Make my app only available to people in a certain country?

Tags: ios, regional

I want to write an iOS app which is only available, usable, or downloadable for people who live in a certain country, for example only to people who live in China or only to people in USA. How could I make this happen?

Comment: Note that, as per Midhun's answer, you can limit the availability of your app, but this is related to the country of the user's iTunes account. There is no guarantee that they are living in that country (although there is a good chance) and it doesn't control where they can use the app once they have downloaded it.

Comment: So, if I understood correctly, if I set my app for USA users only, a user who lives in China can go to his iTunes preferences, set his country to USA and still be able to download my app? Please correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks

Comment: Also, is there any way that I could make the app understand the IP address of the user's phone, and if the IP address is not in USA for example then don't let them to use it?

Comment: You need a us credit card and billing address to set up a us iTunes account, but yes, it can be done. You can try and use gel locking based on IP address but there are vpns and so on that can bypass that too.

Comment: Thanks a lot  Paulw11 and Midhun. I got my answer :))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that in [iTunes Connect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/itc/static/login?view=1&path=%2FWebObjects%2FiTunesConnect.woa%3F).

1. Go to your app's detail page on **iTunes Connect**
2. Choose **App Store** tab
3. Choose **Pricing and Availability** tab situated on the left side
4. Click on the **Edit** button situated under **Availability** section
5. **Select** the territories you want to sell the app
6. Press **Save**

Refer [Changing the Territories Rights Information](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ChangingAppStatus.html) for more detailed information